# Clicking "Monitor Detect"-key with broken fn-key

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, function-keys, fn-key

My <kbd>fn</kbd>-key is broken, but I need it to click the "monitor"-key on my <kbd>f5</kbd>-key.

I need this because my PC isn't detecting my new monitor.

Is there anyway to simulate a <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> click?

Or is there anyway else, to click this key?

Comment: You can probably just use a software keyboard (on-screen) or find a program that lets you re-map keys..

Comment: Do you have a download link for a software keyboard? I already tried a remapping program which included over 30 keys, but none of them were the fn-key, only "Wake (fn)" was included, which didn't work.

Comment: Maybe the built-in Windows one will do it Start > All Programs > Accessories -- in some place like that.

Comment: Doesn't include the fn-key